# Cannot access docker postgres image via intellij and quarkus?

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, quarkus

I run a docker postgres container via command line:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passme -d postgres
```

But in IntelliJ I can't access this container
The following error message occurs:

```
[08001] Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.
```

Do you know any problem, maybe with the port?

Comment: Have you checkout the stdout/stderr of the postgres container? Did the container come up okay?

Comment: Are you able to connect by hand?  `docker run -it some-postgres psql -c 'SELECT 1'`?

Comment: Are you running your quarkus application with docker? If so, I have the same issue. Without docker and plain quarkus it works very well with postgres or mysql.